# Eclipse not properly importing my minecraft mod

Tags: eclipse

It throws me this error every mdk file i use

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8-bin.zip'.
Initialization script 'C:\Users####\eclipse-workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.buildship.core\init.d\eclipsePlugin.gradle'
Could not compile initialization script 'C:\Users####\eclipse-workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.buildship.core\init.d\eclipsePlugin.gradle'.
startup failed:
General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 61
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61

Comment: `Unsupported class file major version 61` means you have compiled code (.class files) of Java 17 code, but Java 17 code is too new here. Does in the project setting the compiler compliance level from 17 to 1.8 (Java 8) work?

Comment: it wont let me access the project settings

Comment: hi sorry i got it fixed, i had to change the gradle version

Comment: Great. Happy coding and minecrafting!